# Htaccess - Hide all dot files/dirs (example .git) except one i.e. ".wellknown"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the following line in my htaccess file to hide all dot files/dirs:

```
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
```

But I want to add an exception that the above rule is not applicable for ".wellkown" folder and its sub files/folders i.e I am able to access ".well-known" folder and file from my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rule as shown in question and create a new file `/www/elgg/.well-known/.htaccess` like this:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: I still don't have permission to access the requested directory.

Comment: Yes, that is the first rewrite rule and there is no other rule conflicting it.

Comment: This is my htacess file. https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/blob/1.12/install/config/htaccess.dist
I am trying to edit line #128

Comment: Yes change line # 128 by this suggested line and as I told you this rule works fine on my Apache.

Comment: Does `/.well-known/` have a `index.php` or `index.html`? If not then error is due to `Directory Index not allowed`. Try accessing a valid file inside like `http://localhost/www/elgg/.well-known/file.php` (make sure file.php exists)

Comment: No, /.well-known/ does not have any index file. Yes, file.php or any other file is accessible.

Comment: Yes so problem is not this rule but absence of an `index` file in that directory. Either have an `index` file there OR else add `Options +Indexes` line (see edited answer above)